# How to have Spyder act as command line Python interpreter

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am used to code in Vim and run my scripts on the command line. My coworker uses Spyder, with is, I admit, a very good tool.
The problem comes in scripts that use matplotlib, where Spyder (or IPython) interferes with at least pyplot.show(), which is typically not required in Spyder, and pyplot.savefig(), which causes an unwanted pyplot.show() in Spyder.

I have tried so far, without success:

- ticking 'Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter' in run settings dialog box
- specifying in Spyder the Python interpreter to use when running scripts
- disabling the PYTHONSTARTUP script in Spyder, by pointing to a noop script

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post your Spyder, Matplotlib and Python versions? And also a simple, reproducible example of the code you're running in Spyder? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to go into more detail about the actual problem you're having. I use Spyder a lot (usually with the *Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter* option active and I never saw any difference between Spyder and console behaviour when using matplotlib. The only issue I ever encountered is when running PyQt GUIs from within Spyder, some options/settings are already loaded because Spyder is written in PyQt as well.

Comment: Erh well OK, tried with a simpler script and _Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter_ and it did work as expected: no spurious pyplot.show(). Did not have much time to investigate what went wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:
plot window pane -> Mute inline plotting
Toggle to  enable / disable plotting within spyder plot window pane